# Is there a tail -f equivalent for ls?

Tags: linux, ls, tail

Basically the question is in the title. I want to monitor a directory for new files that are written or deleted, the way I can monitor a log file with `tail -f`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try watch.

Taken from [here](http://beerpla.net/2007/08/04/watch-a-useful-linux-command-you-may-have-never-heard-of/):

```
watch -d ls -l
```

A friend and I tried this a moment ago, it seems that the highlighting doesn't really work correctly, it will highlight a seemingly random selection. I've tried this in an OS X Terminal ssh'd to a RHEL5 machine and my friend has tried in a Ubuntu GUI terminal.

Unfortunately inotifywait is not present on the RHEL5 machine so I can't give any information on the effectiveness of that command.

Comment: `inotifywait` is part of *inotify-tools*.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's probably the preferred solution, especially with a system that you can add binaries to.

Comment: Put the command in quotes if the commands has one or more pipes. `watch -d "ls -l | grep avi"`.

Answer (score 6):

`inotifywait` from *inotify-tools* shows a real-time log of file modifications, similar to `tail -f`.

```
inotifywait -m -q -e create,delete,move /dir
```

`-r` can be added for recursive watches (can be a little slow with many subdirectories), `--format` to change the output format (e.g. add timestamps or join the path & filename).

Example output:

```
/home/grawity/code/bin/ CREATE,ISDIR fallback
/home/grawity/code/bin/ CREATE gnome-inhibit-list
/home/grawity/code/bin/ CREATE k5translate
/home/grawity/code/bin/ MOVED_FROM logout
/home/grawity/code/bin/ DELETE pacman-sigstats
```

*(By the way, tail -f also uses inotify to follow file changes.)*